# Prove that a function is not surjective

Tags: functions

Let $A$ be any (possibly infinite) set. Argue by contradiction to show that there is no surjection from $A \to \{0,1\}^A$

By contradiction I'm assuming that for every element $b \in \{0,1\}^A$, there exists at least one element $a$ in $A$ such that $f(a)=b$. But how can I now claim that $f$ is not surjective?

Comment: You know that there is no surjection from $A$ to $\mathcal{P}(A)$, the power set of $A$. Is there a connection between $\left\{0,1\right\}^A$ and $\mathcal{P}(A)$?

Comment: Ha that's funny, my answer makes the exact opposite assumption as two which halve of the question is known and which is unknown. Well, together your comment and my answer cover everything it seems

Answer (score 1):

Hint: you can think of elements of $\{0, 1\}^A$ as *subsets* of $A$, so $f$ sends each element of $A$ to a set of elements from $A$.

So before worrying too much about surjectivity, you can ponder more 'natural' questions like:

'Wouldn't it be cute if every $a$ is an element of its "own" set $f(a)$?'

'Is this even possible?'

'What about $f$s where NO $a$ is an element of $f(a)$.'

'Ok, now that I cannot choose $f$ myself, but are given one by the assumption, it seems that we are facing a situation where some $a$'s are elements of their own $f(a)$ and others are not. Can we tell the two types of elements of A apart?'

'What would the set of all $a \in A$ with one of these two properties look like?'

Etc, etc, etc. At some point you will have enough feeling for the situation to derive the desired contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that $\left\{0,1\right\}^A\cong \mathcal{P}(A)$. Indeed, given a subset of $A$, you can consider the sequence $(s_a)_{a\in A}$ such that $s_a=1$ if and only if $a\in A$. Conversely each such sequence determines a subset of $A$.

So your question reduces to is there a surjection from $A$ to $\mathcal{P}(A)$, which is impossible.

In case you wonder why the latter statement is true: Suppose $f:A\rightarrow\mathcal{P}(A)$ is a function. Define $B=\left\{a\in A\mid a\notin f(a)\right\}$. Clearly $B\in \mathcal{P}(A)$. Now you can easily show that there is no $a$ such that $f(a)=B$ by considering two cases: $a\in B$ and $a\notin B$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $f\colon A\to \{0,1\}^A$ is a map. Consider $\varphi\colon A\to\{0,1\}$ defined by
$$
\varphi(x)=\begin{cases}
0 & \text{if $f(x)(x)=1$} \\[4px]
1 & \text{if $f(x)(x)=0$}
\end{cases}
$$
Note that $f(x)$ is a map $A\to\{0,1\}$, which we can evaluate at $x$.

In particular, for every $x\in A$, $\varphi(x)\ne f(x)(x)$, so there exists no $x\in A$ with $f(x)=\varphi$. Therefore $f$ is not surjective.